How To Find Users Who Appear Each Day In Data Set
I'm fairly new to pandas and struggling to understand how to use it to allow me to better understand user behavior in my dataset. For each day in my dataset users may have an entry indicating they interacted with some content. I want to understand over time are the same users repeatedly in the data set vs. unique users.
For example, I would like to understand with pandas the number of unique users and number of users who like user #2 repeat.



ds
userid
unique_content_id




2024-01-26
1
8fd


2024-01-26
2
7rt


2024-01-26
4
6as


2024-01-27
2
45t


2024-01-27
1
8fd


2024-01-27
2
7rt


2024-01-28
4
6as


2024-01-28
7
45t


2024-01-28
7
49t


2024-01-29
4
6as


2024-01-29
2
45t



For output I would like to understand:

Repeat users across different days: 3 users have repeat entries
Unique users: 1 user was unique only visiting on one day


Please clarify your question, what would be the expected output given the provided input? and why?

@mozway Added output

You can use the number of different days per user with groupby.nunique:
df.groupby('userid')['ds'].nunique()

# userid
# 1    2
# 2    3
# 4    3
# 7    1
# Name: ds, dtype: int64

Then you can count those with more than a unique visit with gt + value_counts:
df.groupby('userid')['ds'].nunique().gt(1).value_counts()

# ds
# True     3
# False    1
# Name: count, dtype: int64

True represents the users with more than one visit and False those with a unique visit.
You can get a more friendly output by combining this with cut:
out = (pd.cut(df.groupby('userid')['ds'].nunique(),
              bins=[0, 1, np.inf],
              labels=['unique', 'several'])
         .value_counts(sort=False)
      )

# ds
# unique     1
# several    3
# Name: count, dtype: int64

Which also makes it easier to generalize to more categories:
out = (pd.cut(df.groupby('userid')['ds'].nunique(),
              bins=[0, 1, 2, np.inf],
              labels=['unique', 'twice', '>2'])
         .value_counts(sort=False)
      )

out

# ds
# unique    1
# twice     1
# >2        2
# Name: count, dtype: int64

